# How should I pass a raw query response to a Serializer class?

Tags: sql, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to fetch data using raw sql query but I am facing issues when I am trying to pass the raw sql response to the Serializer class.

Serializer

```
class User_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
      model = Users
      fields = '__all__'
```

View

```
class UserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, emailId, format=None):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
            resRow = cursor.fetchone()
        serializerResponse = User_Serializer(resRow)
        return Response(serializerResponse.data)
```

I realise that the Serializer class cannot work with the ModelSerialzier class in this scenerio. How should I build my Serializer considering the fact that I need to post and save data to the concerned model using this Serializer class.

Comment: Why do you use a raw query in the first place?

Comment: I am not willing to stick to a single framework and I am in a learning phase, so writing native SQL queries can help me get better in them.

Comment: but imagine that you migrate to a new framework, then that will require work as well to translate the queries. Furthermore by using raw queries, you make it harder to adapt the database if you for example move from an sqlite database to a postgreSQL database.

Comment: I would highly appreciate if anyone helps me out with my question !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a connection manually use your model manager's `raw` method. It will return a `RawQuerySet` instance and will be iterable just like regular `QuerySet`. Also all the records that was fetched from db will be a model instance. You can use it like:

```py
users = User.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM users_user")
serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
serializer.data
```

Don't forget to check out [raw sql documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries).

Comment: I don't think the serializer class I mentioned here, will be able to process a raw query set !